# c# Selenium Select Input based on Span Text

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to select a radio button based on the name of the address.  Below I need to select either the span that has the name or the radio button itself.  Either way looks like it will select the radio button.  I need to do this based on the name within the span class.  There are a random amount of spaces before the name of the person so instead of a StartsWith I've been trying to do this with a contains John Doe.

```
<div data-a-input-name="selectedAddress" class="a-radio">
   <label><input name="selectedAddress" value="113290190603" type="radio">
    <i class="a-icon a-icon-radio"></i>
     <span class="a-label a-radio-label">
         John Doe, Something RD, Some City, State, #####-####, Phone: #####
     </span>
   </label>
</div>
```

I can't seem to get the correct syntax regardless of all the ways I've tried.  Here are some of the syntax I tried:

```
var Xpath = "//span[contains(@class,'a-label a-radio-label')][contains(text(),'" + shipName + "')]]";

            var radio = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(Xpath));
            radio.Click();
```

And this:

```
var Xpath = ".//input[following-sibling::strong[contains(.,'" + shipName + "')]]";
            var radio = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(Xpath));
            radio.Click();
```

I cannot point to a specific point with XPath because the item I am looking for might not necessarily be in the same ordered location.  That is why I need to search for it by name. I also cannot do it by the value of the input as I do not know that information beforehand.  I've actually tried many other variances of the two XPATH syntaxes shown above, but those are what I have left now as examples.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your first XPath contains extra closing square bracket. To validate your second XPath provide with HTML code sample for `input` node (I don't see `strong` node in provided HTML)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below XPath to locate required radio-button by partial text:

```
"//label[contains(.,'" + shipName + "')]"
```